# Parallelization of a Shell + Python File Read/Write Problem

Tags: python, bash, parallel-processing

I have a project where I have to regularly use a shell script that does some pre-processing of files.  It has to be done this way per project requirements and legacy reasons - I've inherited a large portion of this code.

Once those files are processed, the output files are FURTHER processed by a Python script.

Is there any good way to run this in parallel?  Right now, this is how my workflow looks.

```
Call shell script, processing thousands of files.
Once finished, call Python script, processing even more files.
Once finished, call SQL script to insert all of these files into a database.
```

If it's possible to parallelize either as a group of ( One file shell --> Python --> SQL ) or parallelize each task ( Parallel shell, Parallel Python, Parallel SQL ) that'd be great.  Everything I've read though seems to imply this is a logistical nightmare due to running into issues with R/W. Is this true and if not any points in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

For a shell, you can use xargs to run multiple processes in parallel.

Example:

```
echo dir1 dir2 dir3 | xargs -P 3 -I NAME tar czf NAME.tar.gz NAME
```

Key `-P` - say xargs run 3 parrallel process.

For a python, you can use [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)! from futures.

For SQL I can’t tell anything, I need to look at which database you are using.